# Accessing JSON Extras in Urban Airship for Android

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I saw this link on Urban Airship's website, stating that C2DM pushes require the new JSON key/value pair configuration: http://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/79134-sending-extras-in-your-android-push

My question is, how do I access these extras inside my IntentReceiver? All of the API references I can find refer to the old string-based method of sending extras.

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using in your IntentReceiver, it will make it easier to suggest how to amend it. It looks like its now a JSONObject with another object in it rather than an object with 2 strings in.

Comment: Found the answer, SO won't let me post it yet, intent.getExtras().keySet() allows you to get the list of keys, intent.getStringExtra(key) allows you to get the value referenced by that key.

Comment: I think your comment is a fair enough answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The extra data can also be accessed from the UrbanAirship Inbox

RichPushMessage  message =

UAirship.shared().getRichPushManager().getRichPushInbox().getMessage(messageId);

```
    if(message != null)
    {
    JSONObject jobj = message .getRawMessageJSON(); 

 try {

    JSONObject jobj1 = new JSONObject();
        jobj1 = jobj.getJSONObject("extra");
```

}
catch(Exception e)
{
}